# Ionic tabbing through password and text

Tags: android, forms, cordova, ionic-framework, tabindex

I have a ionic project in which i'm  supposed to tab through  a password fields. Its a usual change password scenario i just can't tab through like i would in PC ,in android the GO button just right away submits the form i want a functionality like  number does in ionic you know the next button please help.

And thanks a bunch in advance.